# Zend Framework Zend_auth sessions getting mixed up

Tags: zend-framework, session, authentication

I've two subdomains. Each subdomain has its own authenticated users database. I'm using

```
$auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
if($auth->hasIdentity()){ }
```

to check user login credentials. It works prefectly for each individual subdomain. But when I log into one subdomain and try to access 'restricted' page in another subdomain without logging out from first subdomain, it takes me thru. Basically 'auth' session of first subdomain returns true in '$auth->hasIdentity()' for second subdomain. How can I solve this?

**EDIT: Probably using different auth session names might solve it but since I'm sharing the code between these 2 subdomains, this is not feasible option.**

Comment: minor updates. check the new code

Comment: @SM: please see my comments below in your solution. Thanks.

Comment: post updated with Bootstraping without Zend_Application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do somewhere at top of your Bootstrap

```
protected function _initModifiedSession()
{
    if ($this->hasPluginResource('session'))
    {
        $resourcesOptions = $this->getOption('resources');
        $resourcesOptions['resources']['session']['cookie_domain'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
        $this->setOptions($resourcesOptions);
        $this->bootstrap('session');
    }
}
```

UPDATE1
without Zend_Application

```
    $sessionOptions = array(
        'cookie_domain' => $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']
    );
    Zend_Session::setOptions($sessionOptions);
```

Comment: @SM: there is no class in my bootstrap file. Where should I put it?

Comment: @SM: there are normal function calls in my bootstrap.php file. No class is defined there. I'm using it since version 1.6.5. Though I've upgraded to 1.9.

Comment: @SM: ohh I see, you mean I should put in zend bootstrap class file?

Comment: @SM: I tried to put into Bootstrap class inside zend/application/bootstrap/bootstrap.php file and called inside constructor but it never went inside 'if' condition.

Comment: read zend_manual. bootstaping resources requeres config. application.ini with `resources.session.use_only_cookies = true` for example

Answer (score 1):

You should restrict the auth cookies to the current subdomain.

Comment: @erenon: could you please explain a bit? How can I do that?

Comment: @erenon: do you mean I should simply save subdomain in cookie? But then it could be modified to access second subdomain? right?